# Why I can't convert a list of str to a list of floats?

Tags: python, string, list, csv, floating-point

I'm starting to write a code, but it fails at the beginning.

**This is my code:**

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("QstartRefseqhg19.head"), dialect='excel-tab' )

for row in reader:
    C = row[1].split(",")[1:]
    C1 = [float(i) for i in C]

    print C1
```

**and the error log says:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/geparada/workspace/SJtag/src/TagGen.py", line 8, in <module>
    C1 = [float(i) for i in C]
ValueError: empty string for float()
```

**I've also tried**

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("QstartRefseqhg19.head"), dialect='excel-tab' )

for row in reader:
    C = row[1].split(",")[1:]       
    C1 = map(float, C)        

    print C1
```

**My input file looks like this:**

```
NM_032291   0,227,291,316,388,445,500,676,688,700,725,777,863,956,1031,1532,1660,1787,1847,1959,2115,2248,2451,2516,2681,   tttctctcagcatcttcttggtagcctgcctgtaggtgaagaagcaccagcagcatccatggcctgtcttttggcttaacacttatctcctttggctttgacagcggacggaatagacctcagcagcggcgtggtgaggacttagctgggacctggaatcgtatcctcctgtgttttttcagactccttggaaattaaggaatgcaattctgccaccatgatggaaggattgaaaaaacgtacaaggaaggcctttggaatacggaagaaagaaaaggacactgattctacaggttcaccagatagagatggaattcagcccagcccacacgaaccaccctacaatagcaaagcagagtgtgcgcgtgaaggaggaaaaaaagtttcgaagaaaagcaatggggcaccaaatggattttatgcggaaattgattgggaaagatataactcacctgagctggatgaagaaggctacagcatcagacccgaggaacccggctctaccaaaggaaagcacttttattcttcaagtgaatcggaagaagaagaagaatcacataagaaatttaatatcaagattaaaccattgcaatctaaagacattcttaagaatgctgcaactgtagatgaattgaaggcatcaataggcaacatcgcactttccccatcaccagtgaggaaaagtccgaggcgcagcccgggtgcaattaaaaggaacttatccagtgaagaagtggcaagacccaggcgttccacaccaactccagaacttataagcaaaaagcctccagatgacactacggcccttgctcctctctttggcccaccactagaatcagcttttgatgaacagaagacagaagttcttttagatcagcctgagatatggggttcaggccaaccaattaatccaagcatggagtcgccaaagttaacaaggccttttcccactggaacacctccaccactgcctccaaaaaatgtaccagctaccccaccccgaacaggatcccccttaacaattggaccaggaaatgaccagtcagccacagaggtcaaaattgaaaaactaccatccatcaatgacttggacagcatttttgggccagtattgtcccccaagtctgttgctgttaatgctgaagaaaagtgggtccatttttctgatacatccccggaacatgttactccggagttgactccaagggaaaaagtggtgtccccaccagctacaccagacaacccagctgactccccagctccaggccctctcggccccccaggtcccacaggccccccagggcctcctgggcctcctcgcaatgtactatcgccgctcaatttagaagaagtccagaagaaagtcgctgagcagaccttcattaaagatgattacttagaaacaatctcatctcctaaagattttgggttgggacaaagagcaactccacctcccccaccaccacccacctacaggactgtggtttcgtcccccggacctggctcgggccctggtccggggaccaccagtggtgcatcatcccctgctcgaccagccactcctttggttccttgcagaagtaccactccacctccacctcctccccggcctccatcccggccaaagctacctccaggaaaacctggagttggagatgtgtccagaccttttagccctcccattcattcttccagccctcctccaatagcacccttagcgcgggctgaaagcacttcttcaatatcgtcaaccaattccttgagcgcagccaccactcccacagttgagaatgaacagccttccctcgtttggtttgacagaggaaagttttatttgacttttgaaggttcttccaggggacccagccccctaaccatgggagctcaggacactctccctgttgcagcagcatttacagaaacagtcaatgcctatttcaaaggagcagacccaagcaaatgtatcgttaagattaccggagaaatggtgttgtcatttcctgctggcatcaccagacactttgccaacaacccgtccccagctgctctgacttttcgggtgataaatttcagcaggttagaacacgtcctgccaaacccccaacttctctgctgtgataatacacaaaatgatgccaataccaaggaattctgggtaaacatgccaaatttgatgactcacctaaagaaagtgtctgaacaaaaaccccaggctacatattataacgttgacatgctcaaatatcaggtgtctgcccagggcattcagtccacacctctgaacctggcagtgaattggcgatgtgagccttcaagcactgacctgcgcatagattacaaatataatacagatgcaatgacgactgctgtggccctcaacaatgtgcagttcctggtccccatcgacggaggagtcaccaagctccaggcagtgctcccaccagcagtctggaatgctgaacaacagagaatattgtggaagattcctgatatctctcagaagtcagaaaatggaggggtgggttctttgttggcaagatttcagttatctgaaggcccaagcaaaccttctccattggttgtgcagttcacaagtgaaggaagcaccctttctggctgtgacattgaacttgttggagcagggtatcgattttcactcatcaagaaaaggtttgctgcaggaaaatacttggcagataactaatgaaatcttatgcaaggatttggaggattcatataatggagaactgatgtatgagaaacagattttaattttggtttgatgaaaacaaaccaatatctgcacttgggatatatcaggtggaaagtcaatgactttcatctgtgatttccctcacacactaccatgatgaccagtcctacagtatttacttctaggtgtaatattgttaatggttttaaaatgtaattattgtatttgtaaattgtactctcattccagtaaggcagttagacacttgagttttagcattttaccattcctgaaatggatgtaatttaaactgtggtatgtaaatttaatagtagtattgttgaatggcacaatgcttacagaggtagattgcattttgtcaatatataaaatttaaatataatattgatagctgtcataaagggggtgccacatattaaagaaacttaagtggaaccagaagaaaaagaaacaaacttacttttcttcaatgcttagtatgttttactctagtgctaaataaaaactctatcttcaaatgtttagtgggttaaattgagaaactatttcagaaaaaaattctaaggttacagcatattcaaagaaaagcattagttaccactttttaaaaagcttttttttcaaactgcaaatttcataaaaatgcaaactgtgtaaacagggcctcttatttttataacttgtgtaaaaagggaaagcaattcatatttaaagtttaagtatattaaattataatcaagagtaaagaagatgttgaagtcttaactacttgcccctctctacagtttcgcaaatgtggggattgctgaataatcagtcagactaaaaccaaaattgtgattttaagatttcaagactttccgtagttgaactggttaagaatttttgcttagttactctgaatagatgatcttactcatccagtatgggggaatgatacctcacgtcttcctctttacccacaggaatcaaaacgctgagactgagaattttagggaaaaaaaagtccactgtttagatccagaaggagagttttaatcattgtttatatcatttgagaatgaaaaaataagcttcataaatgaaattctattcacattactgtgtaataaatttccttttggatgattaggattcattgtataaaactgtaaatctttgccattcttggagaagcaaaaggagagttatcaaaaatgtatgtcgtttcatcgttgcaaggtataataaaaactgtaattattcaatctggccctgccatatgaacatttagaaagacaaacttcttcgggagtctcagttgtaaaaccttccctcattaatatctgaaaatgttagtcttcctttaagtcatagaacttatttaaacataaaccaatttctattacaggttatgctattaaatagctgtaattattaagttattatttttataattagttgttaaatttcattttacacccactcaaatttaacaaagaatctttagcccctttaaattttagaattaaattaaatttttaaagttttacttctaaaatgagattgtgactggcaattgtttatagtgaaactttttaaattaatctttgtactcctctatcagtgcttgctaccaagagaatgtccaaaatgatttgttttaccatgggaaaattcttactattcaacaaactctcagttggccccctacagcagtctggtgttgaagtttctttgaacgaactaaatatactcattttatgtaaaggtatccaatttgattttgaaaccaaaatagaaaatgcaaaattctaaattccatgaaacatggaatttatgacaccaaaatcaatggagagtaagcagcagcaaactgagaattatccagcatatgaatataacaatgtgtttttaagtaatcaattcatttaaaaaattgaatattaatacaaagcatattaaaaacatgtaaatatta
NM_001080397    0,397,490,715,1443,1597,1774,1980,  atgatccccgcagccagcagcaccccgccgggagatgccctcttccccagcgtggccccacaggacttctggaggtcccaggtcacgggctactcggggtccgtgacacgacacctcagtcaccgggccaacaacttcaaacgacaccccaagaggaggaagtgcattcgtccctccccacccccgccccccaacaccccgtgcccgcttgagctggtggacttcggggacctgcacccccagaggtccttccgggagctgcttttcaacggctgcattctctttggcatcgagttcagctacgccatggagacggcgtacgtgaccccggtgctcctgcagatgggcctgcccgaccagctctacagcctggtgtggttcatcagccccatcctcggattcctactgcagcctctgttgggtgcttggagtgaccggtgtacctcaaggtttggaaggagacgccctttcattcttgtcctggctataggggcactgctgggcctctcgctcttgctgaatggccgggacattggcatcgccctggctgacgtgaccgggaaccacaagtggggcctgctgctgaccgtgtgcggtgtggtgctgatggactttagcgccgactcggcggacaaccccagccacgcctacatgatggacgtgtgcagccccgcagaccaggaccgaggcctgaacatccacgccctcctggcaggtctcggaggaggctttggatacgtggtcggcggaatccactgggataaaacgggcttcgggagggccctggggggacagctccgagtcatttacctcttcactgcggtcaccctgagcgtcaccaccgtcctgaccctggtcagcatccctgagaggccgctgcggccgccgagtgagaagcgggcagccatgaagagccccagcctcccgctgcccccgtccccacccgtcctgccagaggaaggccctggcgacagcctcccgtcgcacacggccaccaacttctccagccccatctcgccgcccagccccctcacgcccaagtacggcagcttcatcagcagggacagctccctgacgggcatcagcgagttcgcctcatcctttggcacggccaacatagacagcgtcctcattgactgcttcacgggcggccacgacagctacctggccatccctggcagcgtccccaggccgcccatcagcgtcagcttcccccgggcccccgacggcttctaccgccaggaccgtggacttctggagggcagagagggtgccctgacctccggctgtgacggggacattctgagggtgggctccttggacacctctaagccgaggtcatcagggattctgaagagacctcagaccttggccatcccggacgcagccggaggagggggtcccgaaaccagcaggagaaggaatgtgaccttcagtcagcaggtggccaatatcctgctcaacggcgtgaagtatgagagcgagctgacgggctccagcgagcgcgcggagcagcctctgtccgtggggcgcctctgctccaccatctgcaacatgcccaaggcgctacgcaccctctgcgtcaaccacttcctggggtggctctcattcgaggggatgttgctcttctacacagacttcatgggcgaggtggtgtttcagggggaccccaaggccccgcacacatcagaggcgtatcagaagtacaacagcggcgtgaccatgggctgctggggcatgtgtatctacgccttcagtgctgccttctactcagctatcctggagaagctggaggagttcctcagcgtccgcaccctctacttcatcgcctatctcgccttcggcctggggaccgggcttgccaccctctccaggaacctctacgtggtcctgtcgctctgcataacctacgggattttattttccaccctgtgcaccttgccttactcgctgctctgcgattactatcagagtaagaagtttgcagggtccagtgcggacggcacccggcggggcatgggcgtggacatctctctgctgagctgccagtacttcctggctcagattctggtctccctggtcctggggcccctgacctcggccgtgggcagtgccaacggggtgatgtacttctccagcctcgtgtccttcctgggctgcctgtactcctccctgtttgtcatttatgaaattcctcccagcgacgctgcagacgaggagcaccggcccctcctgctgaacgtctgacatcgcggagcctcgactccggacacgcgcctgcacctgggggtctggagcaggccgaccagtgaggaccaaagggccttgttggacagggggactggctgcctactggaatgtaaatatgtgataaaataataaatgacagcggcaaagccta
NM_001145277    0,182,283,388,470,579,757,  gaaacctggtcagagagtcgcaccgcttccgtccgtcggacagaggaacggtggaagtcgccggaagttcggtgggctccaggcgtcgcgatggaggagagcgggtacgagtcggtgctctgtgtcaagcctgacgtccacgtctaccgcatccctccgcgggctaccaaccgtggctacagggctgcggagtggcagctggaccagccatcatggagtggccggctgaggatcactgcaaagggacagatggcctacatcaagctggaggacaggacgtcaggggagctctttgctcaggccccggtggatcagtttcctggcacagctgtggagagtgtgacggattccagcaggtacttcgtgatccgcatcgaagatggaaatgggcgacgggcgtttattggaattggcttcggggaccgaggtgatgcctttgacttcaatgttgcattgcaggaccatttcaagtgggtgaaacagcagtgtgaatttgcaaaacaagcccagaacccagaccaaggccctaaactggacctgggcttcaaggagggccagaccatcaagctcaacatcgcaaacatgaagaagaaggaaggagcagctgggaatccccgagtccggcctgccagcacaggagggctgagcctgcttccccctcccccaggggggaaaacctccaccctgatccctccccctggggagcagttggctgtggggggatccctcgtccagccagcagttgctcccagttcagatcaacttccagccagacccagccaggcacaggctgggtccagttctgacctgagcacggtttttcctcatgtgacttctgggaaggcgctccctcatctgggccaaaggaaggaggacgaagccctcctcagctggcctgtgtttggggcatgaatctctcctctcctccttgtctggctctgttgacaaaccgggcatgtttggcagtaaattggcaccgtgtcacactgtttcctgggattcaagtatgcaaccagaacacaggagaagaaaagctccaggatccctgtccccatctgtcctcttgatgtgagagagactctgagacttcttccatcgcaatgacctgtattaaacacaagccccccaagcaaaagaagaggttgagtttgctgccaggattcagatcagcccttcccagggtctgcaggtgtcacatgatcacagttcagcgggaggctttccgtacccacactggctgtagccacttcagtccatctgccctccagaggaggggtttcttcctgatttttagcaggtttagaggctgcagcttgagctacaatcaggagggaaattggaaggattagcagcttttaaaaatgtttaaatattttgctttgctaatgtgctgatccgcactaactcatctttgcaaaaggaactgctccctcggcgtgccccagctggggcctctgaagggattcctcactgtgggcagctgccctgagcttcaggcagcagtgtttatctctggccagttgtctggtttccatgtattctaggccaggtaggcaacacagagccaaggcgggtgctggaagccagacggaacagtgttggggcaggaaggtggatgctgttgtcatggagctgtgggagttggcactctgtctgctggtggccctctcggctcacatgttcacagtgcagctcctggcagacttgggttttctctttggtggtttctaaagtgccttatctgcaaacaacttcttttctccttcaggaactgtgaatggctagaagaaggagctcagtaaactagaagtccagggttgcttggtttactggtttataagaaatctgaaagcacctctgacattccttttattaactcacctctcagttgaaagatttcttctttgaaaggtcaagaccgtgaactgaaaaaagtgttggcctttttgcgggaccagatttttaagataaaataaatatttttacttctgtcattgtatgtgaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

I'm stack, thanks for your time!!

Comment: debugging tip: before the failing statement, do `print "C:", C`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your input line is ended with a comma, e.g.:

```
0,182,283,388,470,579,757,
```

So naturally, this will be split into:

```
['0', '182', '283', '388', '470', '579', '757', '']
```

The last element will always be an empty string, `''`. You'd need to account for this. One way is simply by ignoring it:

```
C1 = [float(i) for i in C if i]
```

Or by cutting out the last element before casting:

```
C = row[1].split(",")[1:-1]   # the slice will exclude first and last elements
```

Comment: Or you can use the ``strip()`` method first: ``C = row[1].strip(',').split(',')[1:]``

Comment: @Blair: I had to say this. Thanks for pointing that out. My mind seems to have broken at some point yesterday. I hope it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

you could use try/except when converting to float and catch ValueErrors.

```
C = row[1].split(",")[1:] 
    for item in C:
    try:
        convert=float(item)
    except ValueError:
        print "not a number"
```